# Java blinking cursor Ubuntu terminal

Tags: java, ubuntu, terminal

I want to stop the blinking cursor while running a program in Java with a Java command in Ubuntu terminal. How can I do it?

Comment: Nick, your question isn't super clear.  Can you share the steps you're doing, and perhaps a screenshot of what's happening, and then "I want to stop the blinking cursor..." will be clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Your Java program doesn't exactly have control of the terminal the user ran it from. My advice would be to have your program manage its own window which you can control.

But if you don't feel like doing that then one idea is that there are codes which *some* terminals listen for. This is very dependent on what terminal you are using but Linux seems to mostly adhere to a spec.

Ubuntu manpages even lists its codes here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man4/console_codes.4.html

<s>Under `ECMA-48 Set Graphics Rendition` section it says that `ESC [ 25 m` sets `blink off`</s>

*correction, as mentioned by VGR, this controls whether printed text blinks, not the cursor blink*

So search for and try some different codes for your specific terminal and remember to actually run from your terminal as your IDE terminal isn't necessarily the same:

```
// \u001B is ESC
public static final String ESC = "\u001B";
public static final String HIDE_CURSOR = ESC + "[?25l";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.print(HIDE_CURSOR);
    System.out.println("Where'd your cursor go??");
}
```

Comment: I added this code in my code ,but still blinking.I always run programs from ubuntu terminal.

Comment: I found a command to set the cursor blinking off (Command: setterm -cursor off)            How can I run this command from java (like System(arg) or something) ?

Comment: What terminal, specifically, are you using? I'd advise looking for the codes for your terminal and trying them. And no `System.setProperty` and such only sets properties in the JVM.

Comment: “␛[25m” controls whether printed text blinks, not whether the cursor blinks.

Comment: @VGR Thanks for the correction. Do you happen to know the right console code? `ESC[?25l` (as in **l**lama) seems to at least hide the cursor.

Comment: Yes, ␛[?25l is what terminfo calls “civis” (short for “cursor invisible”), at least in the `xterm` definition.  (Which terminfo definition is used depends on the current value of `TERM` environment variable).  The cursor can be restored with terminfo’s “cnorm” sequence, which is ␛[?25h for xterm.  I don’t think there’s a way to make the cursor solid and unblinking.